# What is $\mathbb{Z_{n}}\left [ x \right ]$

Tags: ring-theory, notation

> Question: Show that $\mathbb{Z_{n}}\left [ x \right ]$ has characteristic $n$.

What does $\mathbb{Z_{n}}\left [ x \right ]$ stands for? I'm very sure this is not the gaussian ring.

Comment: It's the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients modulo $n$.

Comment: In questions involving notations, you should always mention where you encountered the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{Z}_n$ be the set of integers $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ equipped with the operations of addition mod $n$ and multiplication mod $n$.  It can be shown this structure is a ring.  $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ is defined as the set of polynomials of the form $a_n x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$, where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ equipped with the usual operations of addition and multiplication of polynomials.  This structure is also a ring.

If we take any polynomial $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$, and add $f(x)$ to itself $n$ times, we get $0$ because $a_i + a_i + \cdots + a_i = na_i = 0 $ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.  Recall that the characteristic of a ring $R$ is defined to be the smallest value of $k$ such that $r+r+\cdots+r=rk=0$ for all $r \in R$.  It is clear then that the characteristic of $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ is at most $n$.  By considering the polynomial $f(x)=a_0=1$, we see that the number of times we need to add $f(x)=1$ to itself to get 0 is at least $n$.  Hence, the characteristic of $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ is exactly $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that we have that the characteristic is $n$, the writer probably has addapted the notation $$\mathbb Z_n:=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z.$$

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing as $(\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z})[x]$, the ring of polynomials with coefficients being the integers $mod$ $n$.